# How to cast between integer and character in Red/System?

Tags: casting, red-system

If I try writing this:

```
foo: "whatever"
bar: 0
if foo/1 <> as char! bar [
    ;-- stuff
]
```

Then I am told:

> Compilation Error: invalid target type casting: char!

But if I omit the as char and write:

```
foo: "whatever"
bar: 0
if foo/1 <> as char! bar [
    ;-- stuff
]
```

Then it tells me:

> Compilation Error: left and right argument must be of same type for: <>

How do I cast an `INTEGER!` to a `CHAR!` in Red/System?

Comment: `if [...]` is not the right syntax, no enclosing brackets required for the conditional expression. The compiler should signal it as an error.

Comment: @DocKimbel Ah, yeah, it was actually a `while` but I changed it to "simplify" the question.  :-/  Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no `CHAR!` datatype in Red/System.

The `BYTE!` datatype maybe what you would like to use.

Documentation: [Red/System Datatypes](http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs.html#section-4)